# ASP.NET MVC plus Silverlight

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight

It seems to me that, for structured development with both depth and breadth of capability, ASP.NET MVC and Silverlight have the potential to make a nice powerful framework with superior UI granularity and reduced AJAX exposure. Have any of you tried building such a stack with future durability in mind?

Comment: web != future durability

Comment: I'm not understanding how the stack would work. Is the silverlight the top of the stack, and consuming data from ASP.NET MVC, the next layer in the stack? Is the ASP.NET a fallback for silverlight (that could share common libraries?)

Comment: For starters, I'm seeing silverlight as a more capable way to handle the Views, and I think it could be partitioned that way. I'm interested to see how well it could be isolated to just that responsibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've built a little test app with SL and MVC.  It didn't work that well but I don't think I was doing right.  I've tried using SL in views but its slow to switch pages since its loading new SL instances all the time.  I've tried a single SL app which meant it contained all the control code as well but that relegates the server to data access which only needs some WCF/Web service code no need for MVC there.

It may work better if we dispense with the idea of there being many view pages.  In my next iteration I shall be using controllers to respond with XML or JSON directly to requests from a Silverlight app which contains the views.   However this approach would still leave some questions unanswered, for example, how does the controller get to have a say in what view is actually displayed?

To be honest, I'm getting the feeling that SL to ASP.NET-MVC are yet shaping up as a good match.  Some web apps may benefit from some SL elements (charting for example) yet the app remain firmly in HTML.  On the other hand, an app whose UI is purely in SL (whilst internally using some similar View/Controller concept) doesn't really need MVC on the server-side.

Its early days, it will take while for us early adopters to see what really works and what doesn't.  There being a beta for version 3 with more coming from MS in the way SL can access serverside data may change things further.

Answer (score 5):

ASP.NET MVC **and** silverlight?

In some ways, it is an either-or choice - your data is displayed either in html/css/js generated by ASP.NET, or in Silverlight. Why mix them? I'm sure that ASP.NET MVC is a good way to deliver Silverlight, but that doesn't necessarily make it part of the same UI.

It's generally about reach vs. richness. A web UI with no Silverlight or Flash can reach more users, but one with Silverlight can have a richer UI. Silverlight is good fun to code in, and I have seen some wonderful apps using Silverlight's streaming video features, but if e.g. you are doing data entry and display, and you don't need the richness of Silverlight, then why not keep the reach and stay in Asp.Net?

If you are going to do the UI in silverlight it makes sense to do all of it in Silverlight. I have had good experiences with all the [ViewModel](http://blogs.conchango.com/davidwynne/archive/2008/12/15/silverlight-and-the-view-viewmodel-pattern.aspx)-view-controller page flow happening inside the Silverlight app, rather than transitioning to another html page and loading a different silverlight app. It's faster and you can do fancy transition or fade-in effects in Silverlight's XAML markup.

Why is "reduced AJAX exposure" a desirable goal? Sites like e.g. Stackoverflow here use AJAX techniques to very good effect.

Stephen Walther's talk at MIX09 shows four pillars of ASP.Net as it currently stands - Forms, MVC, AJAX and Dynamic data. A lot of people are Seeing it as "moving from forms to MVC" but there are other approaches also being developed in the mix.

Comment: AJAX has many benefits, but risks include browser variations in behavior, debugging, JS turned off, execution speed. With Silveright, if it's installed, you can be a little more confident about what you've got to work with, and you can push the boundaries more aggressively.

Comment: I agree with your point about "other approaches" - that's the sense of my question. One "approach" I'm musing about is to take a single MVC implementation and see how little it could be changed while suing Silverlight to enrich the UI. Could be a net plus even though it doesn't max the SL benefit.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question here: [Does Silverlight 3 Change the MVC vs. Silverlight question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670223/does-silverlight-3-change-the-mvc-vs-silverlight-question).  This was in response to SL2 vs. MVC where folks all agreed that they were complimentary technologies.  I'm still not convinced.  My experience has been similar to AnthonyWJones.  Per the previous posts, I tried to mingle them without a lot of success.  Could be my own ignorance, though.  Right now I'm building a Silverlight only application using SL3 beta.  I seem to be a lot closer to my intended effect.  That being, an application with a few database features.  So it didn't make sense to build a completely stand alone app (since the data is central), but I really wanted some Silverlight goodness to render the end result and allow the user to interact.

So where in the hell am I going with all of this?  Based on my experience, this still seems like a YMMV type question.  It really depends on what you're trying to build.  Since I'm light on database, heavy on interaction, I'm biting the bullet with Silverlight 3 and .NET RIA Services for the little database stuff.  If I were writing Stackoverflow, I'd probably do ASP.NET MVC and AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

We are currently using ASP.NET MVC as an alternative to WCF to expose data to Silverlight where our Silverlight app makes RESTFUL calls to urls in our Mvc application and the controller returns a JsonResult which works well for us. It's by no means necessarily the text book way but we found this way the two technologies compliment each other. Now if we ever need an HTML implementation we've already done the Model-Controller work which can be re-used.

Comment: This has probably been superseded by ASP.NET web api as a better alternative for REST.