# .NET RIA Services with MVC Style Repositories?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, repository-pattern, ria

I have a Solution with several projects in it, including two asp.net mvc projects that share a Repositories and Models that live in a external assembly (also in the same solution). Essentially...

Core/
-Repositories
-Models

Domestic.Web/
-Basic MVC Site, references the core project

International.Web/
-Basic MVC Site, references the core project

What I want to do is build a Silverlight 3 / RIA Services application for all the database admin. Thats fine except RIA Services (for the most part) is only really documented with the Entity Framework - you can find some info on Linq2Sql and even less on backing RIA with POCO.

What I need is the best references you have on using RIA with POCO but even better if there is some documentation on using it with a MVC / Nerddiner style Repository pattern.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you implemented projects using RIA Services + Coolite and MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We in the RIA Services team are working on a sample MVC application using RIA Services for Domain Logic. We should have the sample posted by next week.
I'll ping you when the Sample goes live.

**EDIT:**

Here is the link to the sample. Much much later than I think Saurabh intended :)

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Repository-Pattern-Demo-fece07ed/

Comment: That should certainly help. I could then conceivably build one RIA service and consume it from both silverlight and MVC? Is that the idea there?

My other choice is to build a straight up WCF service and consume it from silverlight and mvc - but that isn't much different / better.

I was hoping the example sfor a POCO provider would help, could simply use the Repository to supply the data as normal but there are few good POCO examples as well.

Comment: Please update this answer with the links. Current answer is not helpful.

Comment: Hi Saurabh

Have your sample done? Can you post the link here as well? I am very interested in it too. In fact, I am trying to put EF4 + WCF RIA Services + asp.net MVC + Coolite (Extjs for asp.net) all together in my new project.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Getting started with the repository pattern in Silverlight

http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2009/02/18/getting-started-with-the-repository-pattern-in-silverlight.aspx

Comment: Maybe Im'm not up ont he related terminology, but that blog entry doesn't seem to touch on the RIA services Unless that is what the term "ADO.NET Data Service" in the post is referring too).

Thanks for the info though, it is helping form a clearer picture!